# PHP - Extending package eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel

I use a package called [Laravel Mailbox](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-mailbox), which is used to fetch inbound e-mails into your Laravel application.

The [base model](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-mailbox/blob/master/src/InboundEmail.php) in this package looks like this:

```
class InboundEmail extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'mailbox_inbound_emails';

    protected $mimeMessage;
    protected $fillable = [
        'message',
    ];
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->message_id = $model->id();
        });
    }

   ....
   ....
}
```

So this package already have a table defined: `mailbox_inbound_emails`. Now I wish to add a relationship to this model/table, so I have added a custom column to the table, called `stream_token`.

Furthermore, I am extending the model, by using my own model called `Email` - this is so I don't modify the package model directly.

This is my Email model:

```
class Email extends InboundEmail
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'stream_token',
    ];

    public function __invoke(InboundEmail $email, $token)
    {
        // Handle the incoming email
        return $this->stream();
    }

    /**
     * An email belongs to a Stream.
     */
    public function stream()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class, 'token');
    }
}
```

In my `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot()` method, I have this:

```
public function boot()
{
    Mailbox::from('{token}@mydomain.com', Email::class);
}
```

So when I send an email from example: myname@mydomain.com, the `$token` variable is available inside my `Email.php`'s `__invoke()` class.

If I do this:

```
public function __invoke(InboundEmail $email, $token)
{
    Log::debug($token)
}
```

It will output: `myname`

Now, I get an error when above is being executed, because it cannot insert into the database. The error is:

```
local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'stream_token' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `mailbox_inbound_emails` (`message`, `message_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (My email message...)
```

So as you can see, it doesn't even consider the `stream_token` when doing the inserting to the database.

How can I do, so I can extend the packages model and adding a relationship?

Comment: Could you please post the point where you are saving the model instance to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason for this was actually very simple. When I pulled in the package by running `composer require beyondcode/laravel-mailbox` it did not pull in the latest changes, thus it was not using my custom model `Email.php`.

I ran `composer require --dev beyondcode/laravel`, which included the latest commits.

This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should make `nullable` your `stream_token` filed in the database. It does not have a default value.

Try to replace `token` with `stream_token`:

```
//instead of
return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class, 'token');
//do this:
return $this->belongsTo(Stream::class, 'stream_token');
```

Also, I would provide the foregn key as a third parameter here.

Comment: I want to add the relationship, so the `Email` model will provide the `stream_token` to the email.

Comment: That is ok, but this error is most probably caused by the fact that you don't have a default value to that field and the field is not nullable.

Comment: Yes, that's the cause of the error, but there should be a value passed to `stream_token` by the relationship.

Comment: Try to replace `token` with `stream_token`: